# Сложное разделение строки в js

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, строки, split

помогите пожалуйста, есть к примеру текст

```
'Hello, "a man, who is not a man"!'
```

нужно разделить эту строку по запятым, но чтобы запятая в кавычках не была затронута.

Т. е. из `'Hello, "a man, who is not a man"!'` в `['Hello', '"a man, who is not a man"!']`.

P. S. Кавычек может быть более одной пары и могут быть одинарными.

Пробовал написать свой split, но он не универсален и работает только если есть одна пара кавычек:

```
function split_(str, symbols) {
    let str_ = '';
    let res = [];
    let a = true;
    for (let t = 0; t < str.length; t++) {
        if (symbols.includes(str[t]) === false || t > str.indexOf('"') && t < str.lastIndexOf('"') || t > str.indexOf("'") && t < str.lastIndexOf("'")) {
            str_ += str[t];
        } else {
            res.push(str_.trim());
            str_ = '';
        }
    }
    res.push(str_.trim());
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Пробовал написать свою split функцию. Код добавил.

Comment: что находится в параметре symbols?

Comment: может быть случай одной кавычкой? `'abc, def, g"hk, lmn'` как ее рассматривать в данном случае?

Comment: Символы на которые делится строка, изначально подразумевалось их несколько.

Comment: В случае с одной кавычкой, не рассматривать её вообще. Только с парами, если кавычек нечётное количество, то рассматриваем по порядку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```js
const text = 'Hello, "a man, who is not a man"!';
const matches = text.match(/(?:"[^"]*"|[^,"])+/g).map(x => x.trim());
console.log(matches)
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/Y7qCqM/1). Оно находит

- `(?:` - начало незахватывающей подмаски:

  - `"[^"]*"` - символ `"`, затем ноль и более символов, отличных от `"`, а потом символ `"`
  - `|` - или
  - `[^,"]` - один символ, отичный от `,` и `"`
- `)+` - конец незахватывающей подмаски, повторить 1 и более раз.

Пробельные символы в начале и конце каждого совпадения удаляются с помощью `.map(x => x.trim())`.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Никита Если ответ помог решить проблему, пожалуйста, отметьте его как решение, поставив галочку напротив.

Comment: если подмаска не захватывающая, то что тогда match выбирает? Или он просто в отдельную группу это все не кладет?

Comment: @Grundy Текст, найденный шаблоном незахватывающей подмаски, не помещается в отдельный буфер, слот памяти, а добавляется только к тексту всего совпадения.

Comment: если убрать `?:` - результат вроде как тот же самый получается. Есть какая-то принципиальная разница? Например в производительности?

Comment: @Grundy Именно в производительности.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, только за счет выделения памяти на группу? Или на скорость поиска тоже как-то влияет?

Comment: @Grundy За счёт выделения памяти и постоянного перезаписывания его содержимого.